# scala - extracting and concatenating multiple elements from nested arrays of stings

Tags: arrays, scala

I am new to Scala and this is and could use some help. I have an RDD that is Array[Array[String]]. I need to extract the 1st element (ipaddress) and 4th element in each internal array (timestamp). Sample records look like:

```
results: Array[Array[String]] = 
Array
(Array(217.150.149.167, -, 4712, [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06, +0100], "GET, /ronin_s4.jpg), 
 Array(104.184.210.93, -, 28402, [15/Sep/2013:23:42:53, +0100], "GET, /titanic_2200.jpg), 
 Array(37.91.137.134, -, 36171, [15/Sep/2013:23:39:33, +0100], "GET, /ronin_novelty_note_3.jpg)
)
```

I need the results to be:

```
217.150.149.167/15/Sep/2013:23:56:06
104.184.210.93/15/Sep/2013:23:42:53
37.91.137.134/15/Sep/2013:23:39:33
```

so I need to some thow replace the "[" with a "/"  and make a concatenated string of the 2 elemeents.  any ideas would be greatly appricated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I can extract the first element and the 4 element separetly... val IPaddress = results.flatMap(_.headOption) 
val results2 = inputJPG.flatMap (x=>x.split(" ")) 
val Timestamp = results2.filter(x=>x.contains("["))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results.map { arr => { arr(0) + "/" + arr(3).replace("[", "").replace("]","") }}
```

This will return `Array[String]` in the format you state above

Comment: scala> results.flatMap {
     |   _.map {
     |     nestedArr => nestedArr(0) + nestedArr(3).replace("[", "").replace("]","")
     |   }
     | }
<console>:32: error: value replace is not a member of Char
                  nestedArr => nestedArr(0) + nestedArr(3).replace("[", "").replace("]","")
                                                           ^
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Nothing]
 required: TraversableOnce[?]
                _.map {
                      ^

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!